# Is US 2014/0060450 A1 patented or pending?

Tags: patent-pending, us20140060450

I am trying to find out if this patent exist or is it pending.

Answer (score 1):

As per USPTO PAIR

http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair/

Patent application abandoned on 2 Jan 2015 because of failure to respond action.